# param is missing or the value is empty:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, parameters, controller, back

When going on the view page, the error "param is missing or the value is empty: restaurant" is displayed. 
- I solve the problem by deleting "require(:restaurant)" but don't really understand the trick...do you ? 
- I am looking for a solution that allows me to keep the "require(:restaurant)... Any Idea ?

**restaurants_controller.rb**

```
class RestaurantsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_restaurant, only: [:show, :edit, :update]
  def index
    @restaurants = Restaurant.all
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @restaurant = Restaurant.new(params.permit(:name, :address, :category))
  end

  def create
    @restaurant = Restaurant.new(restaurant_params)
    @restaurant.save
    redirect_to restaurant_path(@restaurant)
  end

  private

  def set_restaurant
    @restaurant = Restaurant.find(params[:id])
  end

  def restaurant_params
    params.require(:restaurant).permit(:name, :address, :category)
  end
end
```

**new.html.erb**

```
<%= simple_form_for(@restaurant) do |f| %>
  <% if @restaurant.errors.any? %>
    <div class="errors-container">
      <ul>
        <% @restaurant.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
          <li><%= message %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.input :name %>
  <%= f.input :address %>
  <%= f.input :category %>
  <%= f.submit "add a resto", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

**restaurant.rb**

```
class Restaurant < ApplicationRecord
  validates :name, :address, :category, presence: true
  validates :category, inclusion: { in: ["chinese", "italian", "japanese", "french", "belgian"]}
  has_many :reviews, dependent: :destroy
end
```

**routes**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :restaurants, only: [:new, :create, :show, :index] do
    resources :reviews, only: [ :new, :create ]
  end
end
```

Comment: Are you talking about `new` action? Usually it doesn't need anything except `@restaurant = Restaurant.new` inside it. Do you really pass any parameters to the new action?

Comment: I would think your `new` would have `@restaurant = Restaurant.new(restaurant_params)`. `restaurant_params` does the rest of the work for you. If you *require* the `restaurant` param, then make sure your view is submitting a value for it. Is it? Does your model indicate that it's a required field?

Comment: You were right I put the restaurant_params both in def new & def create but only need it in the def create. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

The inputs of your form should be named like this:

```
    restaurant[name]
    restaurant[address]
    restaurant[category]
```

It could be that it is something like is:

```
name
address
category
```

You can debug your params by inspecting it.
You could do something like this in your restaurant_params in the controller:

```
raise params.inspect
```

Or open your debug console of the browser and see what is posted.

And as mentioned in the comments you can use the restaurant_params in your new method but I don't think that fixes you issue it is more likely that the form is the problem.

```
# instead of
Restaurant.new(params.permit(:name, :address, :category))
# do
Restaurant.new(restaurant_params)
```

Comment: Thank you, I put the restaurant_params both in def new & def create but only need it in the def create :)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're trying to auto-populate the form on your `new` view with some passed attributes.

Your `restaurant#new` is looking for a params[:restaurant] hash to create a new `Restaurant` object and can't find it. Look at how you're calling the `new` action and what parameters are being passed -- my guess is that you're not passing any or you're passing them in the root params hash like `params[:name]`, `params[:address]` instead of `params[:restaurant] => { :name => 'name'}`.

Most `new` actions are a GET so if you're using inline URL parameters put them in like `http://address.com/restaurant/new?restaurant[name]=Bistro&restaurant[category]=burgers`

Comment: Thank you, I put the restaurant_params both in def new & def create but only need it in the def create :)

Answer (score 0):

In restaurants_controller.rb, we can declare a method for show like:

def show
@restaurant = Restaurant.find(params[:id])
end

In the View Section where we want to link with a button, we can paste

```
      <td><%= link_to "Show", restaurant %> </td>
```

I hope it will work